# search for new music videos this week youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

i need to implement several ways to search for songs from youtube or vevo in youtube .. does anyone knows how to do so ?

i need to search for :

- Popular by genres (the response contains several genres and artists in this genre and songs of the artist .. a tree)
- Popular music videos
- Latest music videos
- New music this week

When I try the `URLs` provided by YouTube's API documentation, for example

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?v=2&alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos
```

I receive the following error:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
<error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>NoLongerAvailableException</code>
    <internalReason>No longer available</internalReason>
</error>
</errors>
```

It seems as though Google has migrated to Version 3 without updating their documentation to reflect this. I need to know what are the `URLs` to use in that case so i can find what i am looking for.

Comment: I suggest you start here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?hl=en

Comment: i did start here and i just didn't know how to o those .. found the search by name of the song or id but not these .. @JoshuaCook

Comment: Your question shows very little effort on your part. When seeking assistance here, it is expected that you will document well what you have tried and why you think what you have tried is not working. The way you have phrased this, it is as if you are asking the community to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to begin to figure out the way that YouTube's API works.

I would suggest starting with simpler, more well defined tasks for you to solve.

A list of these tasks might look like this:

1) Very that you are able to communicate with the API itself. A simple "hello, world" type case. Of course this will necessitate figuring out how you will be communicating with the API. Will you send `curl` requests from the command line? Will you use a service like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)? Will you try to implement some sort of minimal app like [Google's sample app](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client)? The bottom line is that you should establish a **VERY** simple connection with YouTube's API. I would start here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby#search_by_keyword

2) Once you have done that move on to a *slightly* more complicated case, for example, searching for a simple term.

Look I get it, Google provides very little support. But I found all of this info in the last 20 minutes.